# BeautifulSoup exact regex match on text

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Say I have the following HTML:

```
html = """
<tag1> What I want </tag1>
<tag1> Not What I want - really not </tag1>
<tag1> What I want </tag1>
<tag1> What I
       Want </tag1>
"""
```

I want to extract all but the 2nd item - to have the tags with exactly the words "What I want" and no other alphanumeric characters. I tried using BeautifulSoup4's find_all with a regex filter as such:

```
html.find_all(string=re.compile(r"\W*what\W*I\W*want\W*", re.IGNORECASE))
```

but this returns all tags in the previous example. I want an exact match, not a "contains".

Comment: What are the requirements? What is it about the 2nd tag that you don't want it to match? is it the hyphen?

Comment: @emsimpson92 edited the question - I want an exact match for the tag's string content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^` and `$` characters can be used to mark the beginning and end of a line.

Replacing your regex with `^\W*what\W*I\W*want\W*$` should work for your cases.

Comment: @emsimpson92 Yes, he isn't matching the html string directly. He is using BeautifulSoup which compares only the tags contents. Did you bother reading the question properly?

Comment: [It does](https://regex101.com/r/o8LIUj/5), `\W` would match the newline.

Comment: Right, this does work, thanks! - Out of curiosity, is there no function in BeautifulSoup that would be the equivalent of `re.match`?

Comment: According to the (documentation)[https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression], BeautifulSoup uses the `search()` method for regex, but I believe prepending `^` to your pattern should be enough to get the same behavior.